# F# If Statement List.exists

Tags: list, if-statement, f#, exists, element

This is a School Assignment but everything i am about to post is done by me and me only. Therefore I only require your help for a tiny step in my assignment at which i am stuck.

```
let rec removeDuplicates2 xs =
  match xs with
  |[]->[]
  |y::ys -> if y = (List.exists y ys) then
              (removeDuplicates2 ys)
            else
              y::(removeDuplicates2 ys)

printfn "%A" (removeDuplicates2 [3;1;3;2;1]) // result must be [3;1;2]
```

What i require help for is making the if statement that checks if element y is a member of list ys

at the moment i get the error saying: "This expression was expected to have type
    ''a -> bool'
but here has type
    'bool'"

can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: First, you are comparing `y` with `List.exists y ys` which should return true or false. You probacly wanted to write `if (List.exists y ys) then`

Comment: Second, `List.exists` expects a function. If you want to check whether a list contains an item use `List.contains`

Comment: I think the exercise does not imply the use of standard functions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

List.exists expects the first argument to be a function which will be checked on the element and returns boolean value. You want to check if element is on the list you could write:

```
if List.exists ((=) y) ys then
```

or even:

```
if List.contains y ys then
```

following Panagiotis suggestion.